# Dynamically Injecting Pages with JQuery Mobile and Json

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

and thanks for looking at my question.  I am new to HTML, JQuery, and JSon. I am trying to teach myself with some online tutorials and www.lynda.com training. I'm trying to make a glossary that dynamically displays a list of terms on page, and when clicked displays the term in the header and the definition below that. After searching and experimentation I've made progress, I've got my ul populating from the JSon object and linked to the display page.  But I am at a loss as how to get the display page working.  I thought the answer was in here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html but I can't seem to pull it off, even in Dreamweaver.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LParker/PSntK/3/

HTML:

```
    <!-- Glossary -->
<div data-role="page" id="glossary">
<div data-role="header">
     <h3>
        Glossary
    </h3>
</div>
<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' id='resultsList'>
<!-- keep empty for dynamically added items -->
</ul>
</div>
    <!-- display -->
    <div data-role="page" id="display">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h3>
            Name Goes Here
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <div>Definition goes here</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var jsonObject = {
"results": [{

    "term": "Term One",
        "definition": "This is the definition for Term Two",

},

{
    "term": "Term Two",
        "definition": "This is the definition of Term Two",

}, {
    "term": "Term Three",
        "definition": "This is the definition for Term Three",
}],
    "ok": "true"
}

var resultLength = jsonObject.results.length;
var listItems = [];



for (var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
var term = jsonObject.results[i].term;


//Add result to array
listItems.push("<li><a href='#display'>" + term + " </a></li>");
}

//Append array to list and refresh
$('#resultsList').append(listItems.join(' '));
$('#resultsList').listview('refresh');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all lets get a few things out of the way:

1. Ditch extra commas after each `definition` member of your json object.
2. Put your `#resultsList` listview in a `<div data-role="content"></div>` container.
3. Provide the means to navigate from `#display` page back to `#glossary` page e.g. by adding a standard jQM back button `<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>` in the header of the `#display` page.
4. While working with jQM you need to use proper [event handlers](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

*For brevity I renamed your variable `jsonObject` to `json`.*

You can populate the listview in a more succinct way:

```
$.each(json.results, function(i, term){
    $('#resultsList').append('<li><a href="#display">' + term.term + '</a></li>')
});
$('#resultsList').listview('refresh');
```

Now in that particular case IMHO you don't need to inject pages (although it certainly possible) you can just change content in `#display` page on `pagebeforeshow` event.

For that to happen, since your json object globally available, you can just get an index of a clicked list item, pass it to your `#display` page, use it to access results array of your json object to extract and show term and it's definition.
The simplest way to pass an index is to use a global variable which you set in a `click` event handler.

```
var currentItem = 0;
...
$('#resultsList li').click(function(){
    currentItem = $(this).index();
});
```

Now in `pagebeforeshow` event you do

```
$('#display').on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
    $(this).find('[data-role=header] .ui-title').text(json.results[currentItem].term);
    $('#definition').html(json.results[currentItem].definition);
});
```

Finally here is working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/Ytbhb/)** for you.

Comment: Thank you Peterm!  Wow, very helpful!  After make your suggested changes and anaylizing the code you provided I've got it working now.  I am still having a problem with the function not working when I tried it inthe .on('pageinit').   I am not sure why that isn't working, Im sure I'm doing something wrong!  I also I still need to go over the event handler doc again to see what I'm doing wrong there.  Thanks again.  Now I'm off to try to figure out how to make it load an external .json!  [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LParker/JQpNr/6/)

Comment: Hello @LisaCoxSparksParker, did you manage to make it using an external json?